# Python Pygame RTS py2exe error pygame2exe not working

Tags: python, pygame, py2exe

Project Link:
https://github.com/edwinclement08/Simple_RTS

I am a 12th grader, learning python
I decided to make a minimalistic working game that has the beginnings of AOE2, kind of.
Currently, I dont have much time and hv to close the project
Though, I am unable to create a standalone EXE, as per our project making guidelines.
turns out pygame doesn't work with py2exe
pygame2exe also doesn't help
will anybody just figure out why doesnt it  EXE-ify.
thanks in advance
i may not respond quickly, am not allowed much time on internet, so please forgive my negligence.

EDIT:->
That's the error screenshot with py2exe.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f22vc7xpj50lhue/Screenshot%202014-12-11%2021.42.36.png?dl=0

Seems to be a font problem.
Already tried Pygame2exe. This is what comes up now.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hyqb817ntzoixvd/Screenshot%202014-12-11%2021.45.53.png?dl=0

This is how it should actually look(I mean when run directly from .py).
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e259pjaoohdwrb0/Screenshot%202014-12-11%2021.48.23.png?dl=0

By the way, I tried to flatten out the directories and put all the files in the main folder with the .py files.
This is the new game folder:->
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b41fhhjc1hzk9k6/Game.zip?dl=0

Comment: what errors are you encountering?  What is happening?  I've worked with py2exe with pygame and found that fonts tend to be the biggest hurdle, but otherwise it works like a charm.

Comment: From @oxrock (not enough rep to comment) : py2exe most certainly does work with pygame, I've used it many times for that purpose. What problems are you running into exactly and what steps have you taken to try and fix it?

Comment: That's the error screenshot with py2exe.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f22vc7xpj50lhue/Screenshot%202014-12-11%2021.42.36.png?dl=0
Seems to be a font problem.
Already tried Pygame2exe. This is what comes up now.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hyqb817ntzoixvd/Screenshot%202014-12-11%2021.45.53.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. Well, kind of.
I used portable python and installed it with pygame.
then i made a python program to initialize my program.
I made another executable file by using RapidQ which uses shell RUN command to run the starts the initializer using the portable python. A little slow but gets the thing done.
I am wondering why nobody thought of this. Seems pretty simple if all you want to do is to distribute your application.

Here's a link to the compressed file for the lazy ones:->
https://www.dropbox.com/s/turo9kq7p06zoia/Python_pygame_make_it_executable.exe?dl=0